# python matrix.dot(matrix.T) symetric output calculation boost

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, dot-product, openblas

Just a question :
If the result of a dot product I want to produce is symetric

```
A = numpy.random.random((3, 3)) # edited
M = A.dot(A.T)
M
[[ 0.          0.11456226  0.1573452 ]
 [ 0.11456226  0.          0.00363075]
 [ 0.1573452   0.00363075  0.        ]]
```

for instance

Is numpy going to copy Mij to Mji's by itself or is there a way to ask for it manualy ? maybe OpenBLAS ?

thanks

Comment: Coul you provide the value of `A`?

Comment: It is a square matrix and can be pure random or anything 
A = numpy.random.random((3, 3))